# A Function take 'N' as argument, performs an Increase N times of Elements then decrease (N-1) times and then return as a list in the Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The problem is, suppose I pass **'N' = 9** to the function,

So the list will be
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1].
At first, the list elements **increased to (1-9)** then it **decreased to reversed order (8-1)**

Please suggest the easiest way to achieve this.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range

Answer (score 2):

```py
list(range(1, 1+N)) + list(range(N-1, 0, -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to achieve in one line. First we have the list comprehension which has a simple loop that appends the number from 1 to `n`. The second is a list comprehension where the numbers in the for loop are passed through the equation `(n+1)-i`. This is to calculate the difference between the current value of `i` and `n+1`. This gives us the pattern of descending numbers. Finally, both lists are added and stored in the variable `r`.

`r = [x for x in range(1,n+1)] + [n+1-i for i in range(2, n+1)]`

When `r` is printed out it produces the following output.

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to use a range from -8 to 8 and output the difference from 9 (ignoring the sign):

```
N = 9

print([N-abs(i) for i in range(1-N,N)])

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

the `range(1-N,N)` will generate:

```
-8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

in absolute value this will be:

```
8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

difference from 9

```
9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9
8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 -
-------------------------------------------------
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```